# Boolean Comparison across multiple dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an issue where I want to compare values across multiple dataframes.  Here is a snippet example:

```
data0 = [[1,'01-01'],[2,'01-02']]
data1 = [[11,'02-30'],[12,'02-25']]
data2 = [[8,'02-30'],[22,'02-25']]
data3 = [[7,'02-30'],[5,'02-25']]
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data0,columns=['Data',"date"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Data',"date"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['Data',"date"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3,columns=['Data',"date"])
result=(df0['Data']| df1['Data'])>(df2['Data'] | df3['Data'])
```

What I would like to do as I hope it can be seen is say if a value in `df0` `rowX` or `df1` `rowX` is greater than `df2` `rowX` or `df3` `rowX` return `True` else it should be `false`.  In the code above 11 in `df1` is greater than both 8 and 7 (df2 and 3 respectively) so the result should be True and then for the second row neither 2 or 12 is greater than 22 (df2) so should be False.  However, result gives me

```
False,False
```

instead of

```
True,False
```

any thoughts or help?

Comment: Are the sizes and columns identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

For your data:

```
>>> df0['Data']
0    1
1    2
Name: Data, dtype: int64
>>> df1['Data']
0    11
1    12
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

your a doing a *bitwise or* with  `|`:

```
>>> df0['Data']| df1['Data']
0    11
1    14
Name: Data, dtype: int64
>>> df2['Data']| df3['Data']
0    15
1    23
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

Do this for the single numbers:

```
>>> 1 | 11
11
>>> 2 | 12
14
```

This is not what you want.

### Solution

You can use `np.maximum` for find the biggest values from each series:

```
>>> np.maximum(df0['Data'], df1['Data']) > np.maximum(df2['Data'], df3['Data'])
0     True
1    False
Name: Data, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Well, not totally. `np.max([a, b], axis=0)` returns a NumPy array, whereas `np.maxium(a, b)` returns a series if `a` and `b ` are series.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing solution does not work because the `|` operator performs a *bitwise* OR operation on the elements.

```
df0.Data | df1.Data

0    11
1    14
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

This results in you comparing values that are *different* to the values in your dataframe columns. In summary, your approach does not compare values as you'd expect.

---

You can make this easy by finding -

- the max per row of `df0` and `df1`, and
- the max per row of `df2` and `df3`

Comparing these two columns to retrieve your result -

```
i = np.max([df0.Data, df1.Data], axis=0)
j = np.max([df2.Data, df3.Data], axis=0)

i > j
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

This approach happens to be extremely scalable for any number of dataframes.